# Why is "now and then" used to mean the opposite of its logical meaning?

Tags: meaning, expressions, history

Why and when did the expression "now and then" come to mean sometimes or occasionally? Logically it means just the opposite! "Now" and "then" means "presently" and "in the past", the future will soon become the "now" and then the "then." So if something happens "now and then" it happens all the time, and will continue to do so.

When did we start using it to mean "occasionally"?

Comment: My bad, I should have used the full version of the expression. It d

Comment: My bad I really should have given the full expression. "Every now and then". Therefore logically every now would be all present periods regardless of length. Every now would then become every then, in other words the past, present and future as every future moment will become a present moment and then the past. I think a comment from Doctor Who might be useful.

Comment: I edited my response to address your new concern.

Answer (score 4):

**"Now and then"** does not "logically" mean "all the time." It might, however, be ambiguous between a reading on which it means "all the time" (as it seems to mean in the phrase "both now and then") and the reading on which it means "occasionally".

"Now" and "then" can be used deictically to refer to ***momentary instants*** (as in "Now it's midnight"), ***longer periods*** (as in "Now it's August"), or ***much longer periods*** (as in "Now it's the 21st century").

Used to refer to instants, "now and then" can thus communicate something's happening at sporadic moments, or occasionally. I'm not sure about the exact history of this use though.

EDIT: **"Every now and then"** is an interesting variant. But it doesn't raise any special problems.

Just consider that often when we use "every N" (where N is a noun) we don't actually mean to be speaking about every N in existence. When I announce to a class that "Every student is here," I don't mean every student in existence, I just mean "Every student *enrolled in this class* is here." Quantifiers like "every" are said to be ***contextually restricted***.

A similarly restricted use of "every" would explain the meaning of "every now and then" as denoting sporadic moments.

Comment: There analogous spatial idiom being "here and there", and which points up the absurdity of interpreting "now and then" to mean "all the time": *there* is a point, you can't say *there* and mean "everywhere".

Comment: Boats fill Bristol harbour and have done so for centuries.  Both *now and then* the huge tidal range of the Bristol channel has restricted when they can exit the harbour and head out to sea.

Comment: @Dan, I assume you're presenting this as a counter-example to one of my claims? Let me just say that I wasn't giving a full explication of ALL the uses of "now and then," only pointing out that on one use it can be used to denote or communicate about sporadic instances.

Comment: I guess I was wanting to illustrate that the OP has a reasonable question with a logical basis.

Comment: @Dan, I think it is a reasonable question too and I have tried to explain the mechanisms underlying the use of "now and then" to refer to sporadic moments. The words "now" and "then" *can certainly* be used *broadly* to mean "the present" and "the past", respectively (as they are in your example), but they are not always used that way.

Comment: @Silenus - I do agree with you that most usages of 'now' and 'then' in this context whether *now and then* or *now and again* refer to 'points in time' (i.e. precise moments, rather than stretches of time).

Comment: @Dan, I figured. I edited my post to make it clear that I wasn't making an absolute statement about "now and then" and that it might, in fact, be ambiguous between the way you used it in your example and the way suggested by the OP.